# Move elements to new column if height is reached

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a four level menu, and on level3 and level4 I want to use 4 columns. When the first column height is reached from level4 items, elements show on the next column.

```
<pre>
https://jsfiddle.net/nbastreet/Lc9w2nqk/5/
</pre>
```

I tried to use flex display to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. 
You just need to add the `column-count` property to your menu-items container (`<ul>`)

```html
<ul class="column">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.column {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

Here is an example https://codepen.io/kaiten/pen/ddrvMj

You can learn more about column properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: Check the top of the css, ive included a class called `.column` on your level 2 menu, and defined the property called `column-count` with the value setted to 3 https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9w2nqk/13/

Comment: but it does't work and level4 items still is out of container!

Comment: are you watching the same jsfiddle as i am? https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9w2nqk/13/                                                        
for me it works fine, if you want the effect to be aplied on other items, just add the same property for the items container